# ChromeOS Microphone and Camera Access no longer Works on Insecure Origins

Tags: linux, google-chrome, flash, applet, chromebook

Updates to ChromeOS recently made it impossible to access microphone or camera via flash if the address is insecure (ie, http rather than https).

I use an embedded flash applet that requires microphone and camera for my work on ChromeOS (I have an Acer R13). Opening the console shows the following (truncated) error when loading the webpage:

enter?uid=**link**:1 Microphone and Camera access no longer works on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See [link](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins) for more details.

Following instructions given by Google in various places ([1](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins),[2](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags),[3](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/poking-around-your-chrome-os-device)) I enabled dev mode on the Chromebook and edited /etc/chrome_dev.conf with the following tags:

```
--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://url1,http://url2,http://url3,http://ip1,http://ip2,http://ip3,http://url4,http://url5,http://ip4
--user-data-dir=/home/chronos
--allow-running-insecure-content
--reduce-security-for-testing
--user-data-dir=/test/only/profile/dir
```

where all the urls and ips represent every url or ip that returned the error above in console.

Despite allowing the insecure origins, the error for url1, which is the api link for the flash app, won't resolve. If I access the api link directly and specify https protocol, the app behaves as expected, though without proper integration with other features on the original webpage.

I can't perfectly reverse engineer the code, nor could I post it here, but I can tell that the issue is that the embedded flash application is still not allowing camera and mic access correctly; before the flags, the flash application didn't show any microphone or camera in the selection dialogue - after the flags, the devices at least show up, but still don't work, and the error persists.

I wouldn't even mind globally allowing insecure content - since the only website I need to visit on this device is the work website - though I'd prefer such a solution to be tied to a test profile. Any ideas on how I can get proper access here?

Comment: Where you ever capable of fixing this issue?

Comment: Yes, on the server side.  =)

Comment: Seems like I might have to go for the same kind of solution. At this time I think that I am left with adding an ssl certificate.....told my company it should have been done from the beginning. Oh well.....

Comment: My company actually had SSL certs, but the external resource they were embedding did not. If the issue is on your side, there are free ways to do that like https://datacenteroverlords.com/2012/03/01/creating-your-own-ssl-certificate-authority/], but it depends on the source of the issue.